# Haystack SearchIndex model_attr not following relation correctly?

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using Django Haystack v2.0.0 and Whoosh v2.4.0. According to Haystack's [documentation](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0.0/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation) search indexes can use Django's related field lookup in the `model_attr` parameter. However, running the following code using manage.py shell command:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
for r in SearchQuerySet():
    print r.recruitment_agency # Prints True for every job
    print r.recruitment_agency == r.object.employer.recruitment_agency
    # Prints False if r.object.employer.recruitment_agency is False
```

I have tried rebuilding the index several times, the index's directory is writeable, and I don't get any error messages. All other fields work as expected.

I have the following (simplified) models:
companies/models.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    recruitment_agency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

jobs/models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='jobs')
```

jobs/search_indexes.py:

```
class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    recruitment_agency = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='employer__recruitment_agency')

    def get_model(self):
        return Job
```

jobs/forms.py:

```
class JobSearchForm(SearchForm):
    no_recruitment_agencies = forms.BooleanField(label="Hide recruitment agencies", required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(JobSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.cleaned_data['no_recruitment_agencies']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(recruitment_agency=False)

        return sqs
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I am having a [similar problem see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878754/haystack-indexing-related-model-issue), your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I've switched over to the ElasticSearch backend, but the problem persisted, indicating that it might be a problem in haystack, and not in Whoosh.

The problem is that the python values `True` and `False` are not saved as boolean values, but as string, and they are not converted back to boolean values. To filter on boolean values, you have to check for the strings `'true'` and `'false'`:

```
class JobSearchForm(SearchForm):
    no_recruitment_agencies = forms.BooleanField(label="Hide recruitment agencies", required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(JobSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.cleaned_data['no_recruitment_agencies']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(recruitment_agency='false') # Change the filter here

        return sqs
```