# Haystack indexing related model issue

Tags: django, indexing, django-haystack

I want to prepare an index for two models, so I can search text from both models. Below is my code. When I run "python manage.py rebuild_index" I get the error "raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist" for the index line "return obj.mainparts.parts".

models.py

```
class Main(models.Model):
    ....#various fields

class Parts(models.Model):
    main = models.OneToOneField(Main, primary_key=True, related_name='mainparts')
    parts = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

search_indexes.py

```
class MainIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    ....#various fields from class Main
    parts = indexes.CharField()

    def prepare_parts(self, obj):
        return obj.mainparts.parts

    def get_model(self):
        return Main
```

and main_text.txt:

```
{{ object.parts}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.related.model.DoesNotExist` means that there is no `Parts` instance for the `Main` object that haystack is indexing at the time of the error. You can catch the exception and just return an empty string `""` in that case:

```
# ...
def prepare_parts(self, obj):
    try:
        return obj.mainparts.parts
    except Parts.DoesNotExist:
        return ""
# ...
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked, although I also had to change main_text.txt to {{object.mainparts.parts}}. Thanks